# Powershell fails to use keyword 'param' in the second calling function

Tags: powershell, function, parameters

```
function param-simple {
    Param([string]$user_, [string]$host_, [Parameter(position=0,ValueFromRemainingArguments)]$params_)
    write-host "[*]user: $user_"
    write-host "[*]host: $host_"
    for($i=0; $i -lt $params_.count; $i++){ write-host "    [$i] $($params_[$i])" }
}

function param-twice {
    Param([string]$first_, [string]$second_, [string[]][Parameter(position=0,ValueFromRemainingArguments)]$params1_)
    write-host "[-]  first: $first_"
    write-host "[-] second: $second_"
    $params2_ = @()
    $params1_ | foreach-object { $params2_ += $_ }
    param-simple @params2_ # also not work for @params1_, but work for @args
}
```

function param-simple works properly if it's called directly, but it will not if it's called through the function param-twice

```
D:\MyTour\PowerShell01>param-simple -first f -second s -user u -host h 1 2
[*]user: u
[*]host: h
    [0] -first
    [1] f
    [2] -second
    [3] s
    [4] 1
    [5] 2
D:\MyTour\PowerShell01>param-twice -first f -second s -user u -host h 1 2
[-]  first: f
[-] second: s
[*]user:
[*]host:
    [0] -user
    [1] u
    [2] -host
    [3] h
    [4] 1
    [5] 2
```

Would you kindly look into it?

Comment: In the call to ```param-twice```, the “remaining” parameters in ```$param1_``` is this array: ```@(“-user”, “u”,  “-host”, “h”, 1, 2)```. When you “splat” these into ```param-simple``` it *doesn’t* bind them to *named* parameters because you splat an *array*,  not a *hashtable*. Instead, all the values in the array get bundled into ```param-simple```’s “remaining” parameter ```$param_```. Splatting an array only binds to *positional* parameters - see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2#splatting-with-arrays

Comment: I tried to use '`$psboundparameters`, but failed. Is there a function to convert `$params1_` to one hash or array that the second function accepts properly?